# jQuery function preventing nested <body> elements from being read

Tags: html, jquery

My assignment is to create a Twitter clone with HTML, CSS, and jQuery. I have been provided a jQuery function that generates 10 tweets, but when I call it in <scripts>, I am only able to get it to run in the <body> tag, and all of my changes to HTML and CSS are canceled out. Basically it just spits out 10 tweets on top of my singular background.

```js
  <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
     var $body = $('body');
     $body.html('Twitter-Clone');
     var $tweets = $("tweets-container");


     var index = streams.home.length - 1;
     while(index >= 0){
       var tweet = streams.home[index];
       var $tweet = $('<div></div>');
       $tweet.text('@' + tweet.user + ': ' + tweet.message);
       $tweet.appendTo($body);
       index -= 1;
     }

   });

 </script>
```

And if I write something like

```js
    $tweet.appendTo($tweets) <!--or-->
    $tweet.appentTo("#tweets-container");
```

Tweets do not show up at all, AND my page ignores all the HTML and CSS I've written aside from what's at the top of <body>

I really want to know, how can I apply this function to my <div>"tweets-container", and why does the code seem to skip over all of my elements nested in <body> after execution?

I think once I figure this out, it'll be a huge step in the right direction. Any help is very much appreciated! Can supply additional code if needed.

Comment: What exactly do you think `$body.html('Twitter-Clone')` does? I suggest you have a look at the manual page ~ https://api.jquery.com/html/#html2

Comment: Oh my god, all I had to do was remove that line of code and now it works completely fine! I think it was in there as a part of the skeleton I was provided and I assumed that it was just a title. Thank you so much!!

Comment: "When .html() is used to set an element's content, any content that was in that element is completely replaced by the new content." Well that makes a lot of sense now